# Relationship between Convergence and Open sets

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces

If you show that convergence of nets in a topological vector space $V$ with topology $\tau$ is equivalent to convergence of nets in a topological vector space $V$ With topology $\sigma$, does it necessarily follow that $\tau = \sigma$?

Comment: A related question that may help in addition to the responses here illuminate your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69174/if-you-know-the-convergent-sequences-how-do-you-know-the-open-sets

Comment: BTW-I'm going to fix my deleted answer below and repost. I still think it was instructive as it stood,but clearly it confused some people as it stood,so I'm going to try and get it into a form that's "acceptable" to them. That may not be possible,but I will try..........

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You may find this easier to prove by showing that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ have the same closed sets, since closed sets are easier to describe in terms of nets than open sets are.

Comment: It may also be easier to realize that it is true in general for topological spaces, not just for topological vector spaces. If $A$ is a subset of a topological space $X$, then $A$ is closed if and only no net in $A$ converges to a point in $X\setminus A$.  See for example Theorem 2 in Chapter 2 on page 66 of Kelley's *Topology*.