# compactness / sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for two examples:

1. A space which is compact but not sequentially compact
2. A space which is sequentially compact but not compact

Explanations why the spaces are compact / not compact and sequentially compact / not sequentially compact would be appreciated. A reference would also be appreciated. So the conclusion would be, that there's no equivalence in general. Of course they are equivalent in a metric space.

math

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/44907/5363

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/SequentiallyCompact.html , http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sequentially+compact+space here you should find both counterexamples.

Comment: ...and the canonical reference for answering such questions quickly and reliably is Steen and Seebach, *[Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topology.html?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&redir_esc=y)*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following examples are from [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org), a searchable database of Steen and Seebach's [Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topology.html?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC).

(Click on the following links to learn more about the spaces.)

For [compact but not sequentially compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%7ESequentially%20Compact):

- Stone-Cech Compactification of the Integers
- Uncountable Cartesian Product of Unit Interval ($I^I$)

For [sequentially compact but not compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Sequentially%20Compact%2B%7ECompact):

- An Altered Long Line
- $[0, \omega_1)$ ($\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal)
- The Long Line
- Tychonoff Corkscrew

Comment: @ Austin Mohr: My first attempt was Counterexamples in Topology. Without knowing that the Cartesian product of unit interval and $[0,\omega_1)$ are examples, it's hard to find something in there. So thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are tables at the back of the book, where you can find such examples with patience.  And isn't there a Venn diagram in the section on compactness at the beginning?  Of course, the automated Spacebook is easier.

Comment: $I^I$ is correct, but it is wrong to characterize this as "uncountable cartesian product of unit interval" - we need the product to be of cardinality at least the continuum. As [explained by KP Hart](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29220/61785), it is consistent with ZFC that $[0,1]^{\aleph_1}$ is sequentially compact (necessarily with the continuum hypothesis being false).

Answer (score 0):

> **Example 1 with proof:** Stone-Čech Compactification of the Integers $\beta \omega$
>
> **Proof:** It is compact obviously. We will prove that $\beta\omega$ is not sequentially compact. Note that every infinite set in $\beta\omega$ has $2^\mathfrak c$ cluster points, hence the only convergent sequences in $\beta\omega$ are those which are eventually constant; therefore if $X$ is a subspace of $\beta\omega$  and $X$ is sequentially compact, then $X$ is finite. So $\beta\omega$ cannot be sequentially compact.

Comment: Didn't you post this answer somewhere else today?