# Compact space which is not sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology

Greets

So this is exercise 17G.1 of Stephen Willard's "general topology", and it's stated:

> Show that there is a compact space that is not sequentially compact
>
> [Hint: Consider an uncountable product of copies of $[0,1]$]

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152447 and the links and references there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here is my answer

> Let $S$ be the set of all strict increasing sequences of natural numbers, and for each $s\in{S}$ let $X_s=\left\{{0,1}\right\}$ with the discrete topology, put $X=\prod_{s\in{S}}X_s$.
>   Then $X$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. Let us see that $X$ is not sequentially compact. Define $\left\{{x_n}\right\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ as follows:
>   let $s\in{S}$ with $s=\left\{{n_k}\right\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$, then define $(x_n)_s=0$ if $n=n_k$ for some $k$ even and define $(x_n)_s=1$ otherwise.
>   Let us see that $\left\{{x_n}\right\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ has no convergent subsequence in $X$. Let $s\in{S}$ with $s=\left\{{n_k}\right\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$, then $(x_{n_k})_s=0$ for $k$ even and $(x_{n_k})_s=1$ for $k$ odd, thus $\left\{{x_{n_k}}\right\}_{k\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ does not converge in $X=\prod_{s\in{S}}X_s$ since it doesn't converge componentwise.

As you can see this example is too straightforward, and I would like to see other examples.

Thanks.

Comment: You want $s=\{n_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$, not $s=\{n_k\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$. Apart from that the argument is correct, though there are a couple of places where it could be made a little clearer. I don’t think that I’d call it *too* straightforward; it’s one of the two most obvious examples of a compact space that isn’t sequentially compact, the other being $\beta\Bbb N$, the Čech-Stone compactification of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org), a searchable version of Steen and Seebach's [Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topology.html?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC), lists the following compact spaces that are not sequentially compact. You can learn more about these spaces by viewing the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%7ESequentially%20Compact).

Stone-Cech Compactification of the Integers

Uncountable Cartesian Product of Unit Interval ($I^I$)

The second is the one hinted at by Willard.

Comment: You mean that the *second* is the one that Willard suggests.