# Characterization of Connected Components for Compact Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I'm trying to prove the following statement from James Dugundji's Topology (XI - section 2 - problem 6).

> Let $X$ be compact (Hausdorff). Define an equivalence relation $R$ as follows: $xRy$ if for every continuous $f\colon X\to E^1$ such that $f(x)=0$, $f(y)=1$, there is a $u\in X$ with $f(u)=\frac{1}{2}$. Show that the equivalence classes are the components of $X$.

(I'll denote the equivalence class of $x$ as $[x]$ and it's component as $C(x)$).
I want to show that $[x]=C(x)$ for each $x\in X$. Showing $C(x)\subseteq [x]$ is easy: let $y\in C(x)$ and let $f\colon X\to E^1$ be continuous with $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Since $C(x)$ is connected, $f\big(C(x)\big)$ is connected and thus $[0,1]=[f(x),f(y)]\subseteq f(C(x))$. It is then clear that $C(x)\subseteq [x]$.

In order to prove $[x]\subseteq C(x)$, I want prove that $[x]$ is connected. I have no idea how to prove this. We haven't used compactness yet so clearly this is the hard part of the problem. I'm looking for some **hints** on how to proceed

*What are some hints in order to prove $[x]$ is connected?*

Update: I'm now looking for hints, partial solutions, complete solutions, or anything that might allow me to eventually read a proof (either written by me or someone else) of the property.

**Definitions.** A space $X$ is *Connected* if it can't be decomposed into two disjoint open sets (i.e. no continuous $f\colon X\to \{0,1\}$ is surjective). A *connected component* for a point $x$ (written $C(x)$) is defined as the union of all connected sets containing $x$. $E^1$ denotes the first Euclidean space: $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{T})$ where $\mathscr{T}$ is the usual topology.
$[x]=\{y\in X\mid \forall f\in C(X), [(f(x)=0\land f(y)=1)\implies (\exists u\in X,\; f(u)=1/2)]\}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11423/86856 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411400/ (the equivalence classes $[x]$ are called *quasicomponents*, though your definition for them is a little bit unusual).

Comment: maybe is hard to use compacteness because you are not nameing a space were $X$ is compact, and using a cover with some idea of the componets could be usefull as if you show that are finite of them then they are open and can do a cover or some idea like that

Comment: its not true that its necesary finite here are some contraexamples https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220908/966757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Eric Wofsey comments, we can invoke the fact that in compact Hausdorff spaces *components* agree with *quasicomponents*. See [Any two points in a Stone space can be disconnected by clopen sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11412) and [Quasi-components and components coincide for compact Hausdorff spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3411400).

The quasicomponent $Q(x)$ of a point $x$ of a space $X$ is the intersection of all clopen subsets of $X$ containing $x$. This is a closed subset of $X$ which always contains the component $C(x)$ of $x$ in $X$. To see this, let $C \subset X$ be clopen with $x \in C$.  Then $U = C \cap C(x)$ and $V = (X \setminus C) \cap C(x)$ are disjoint open subsets of $C(x)$ such that $U \cup V = C(x)$. Since $C(x)$ is connected and $x \in U$, we conclude $V =\emptyset$ and thus $C(x) \subset C$.

The quasicomponents of $X$ form a partition of $X$ into pairwise disjoint closed subsets of $X$. To see this, let us first show $(1)$ $Q(x) \subset Q(z)$ for all $z \in Q(x)$. Let $C \subset X$ be clopen with $z  \in C$. Assume $x \notin C$. Then $C' = X \setminus C$ is clopen with $x \in C'$, thus $Q(x) \subset C'$. Hence $z \in C' = X \setminus C$ which contradicts $z \in C$. Next let us show $(2)$ $Q(x) = Q(z)$ for all $z \in Q(x)$. In fact, since $x \in Q(x) \subset Q(z)$ we get $Q(z) \subset Q(x)$ by $(1)$. But $(2)$ proves that $Q(x) \cap Q(y) \ne \emptyset$ implies $Q(x) = Q(y)$.

**Lemma.** In an arbitrary space $X$ the equivalence classes with respect to $R$ are the quasicomponents of $X$.

*Proof.* 1. $[x] \subset Q(x)$.

Assume there exists $y \in [x]$ such that $y \notin Q(x)$. Then there exists a clopen $C \subset X$ such that $x \in C$ and $y \notin C$. Define $f : X \to E^1, f(z) = 0$ for $z \in C$ and $f(z) = 1$ for $z \notin C$. This map is continuous wiuth $f(x)= 0$ and $f(y) =1$, but there is no $u \in X$ with $f(u)=1/2$. Hence $y \notin [x]$, a contradiction.

2. $Q(x) \subset [x]$.

Assume there exists $y \in Q(x)$ such that $y \notin [x]$. Then there exists a continuous $f : X \to E^1$ with $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y)= 1$ such that $1/2 \notin f(X)$. The sets $U_1= (-\infty,1/2)$ and $U_2 = (1/2,\infty)$ are disjoint open subsets of $E^1$, thus the $V_i = f^{-1}(U_i)$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$. Since $1/2 \notin f(X)$, we have $V_1 \cup V_2 = X$. Hence $V_1$ is clopen in $X$. Since $x \in V_1$, we have $Q(x) \subset V_1$. But $y \in V_2 = X \setminus V_1$, thus $y \notin Q(x)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $[x]$ is not connected, then it is disconnected. As you say, there is a continuous surjective function $f: [x] \to \{ 0 ; 1 \}$. But this is a continuous function $f : [x] \to E^1$ with at least two points $a,b \in [x]$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$, and with no $u$ with $f(u)= 1/2$.
This is exactly the negation of the hypothesis $a R b$.

Comment: I don't buy it: you are meant to show that there is a $f\colon X\to E^1$ with no $u\in X$ with $f(u)=1/2$ in order to arrive at a contradiction, this is not what you did. As is, I don't think it's trivial, from your proof, that $f\colon [x]\to E^1$ can be extended to $X$ (period) such that there is no $u\in X$ s.t. $f(u)=1/2$. Note that you didn't use compactness and that chapter XI is all about compactness. (I hope to be wrong and corrected btw, thanks for your response).

Comment: I might add that this proof could maybe be corrected by perhaps showing that
$$[x]=\{y\in X\mid \forall f\in C(X), [(f(x)=0\land f(y)=1)\implies (\exists u\in [x],\; f(u)=1/2)]\}$$
and that $[x]$ is closed in $X$ (so that $f:[x]\to \{0,1\}$ can be extended to the whole space through H. Tietze's theorem). This two properties should be true given that we want to show that $[x]=C(x)$.