# FIP nonempty intersection implies sequentially compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, alternative-proof

How do you prove that if closed sets have the FIP in a metric space $K$ then their intersection is nonempty, then the set is also sequentially compact?

I've seen proofs that FIP nonempty intersection is equivalent to compactness and proofs that compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness, but how do you prove it directly?

The converse is easy, but I don't see how to prove this direction..

Comment: "FIP nonempty intersection" is indeed equivalent to compactness, but compactness neither implies nor is implied by sequential compactness. You could maybe find counterexamples to both implications here on MSE.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/compactness-sequentially-compact?s=4|2.8873) for counterexamples.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Supposed to be a metric space

Comment: @StefanHamcke is the answer below correct? it doesn't seem to be

Comment: Okay. Then it is better to mention in your question that you are dealing with metric spaces, so people don't get confused.