# Is there a counterexample such that : $X$ is a topology space , every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point but $X$ is not compact .

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> $X$ is a topology space and $A=\{x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_n , ... \}$ is a subset of $X$ , $y$ is a limit point of $A$ .
>   Can we show that for each $N$ , $y$ is also a limit point of $A'=\{x_N ,x_{N+1}, ... \}$ ?

It is obvious that the conclusion hold when $X$ is a metric space . But it might not be valid for all topology space since if it is true , then we can use it to prove : If every infinite subset in $X$ has a limit point , then $X$ is compact . (Which is not true for all topology space )
Suppose there is family of open sets $O_1,\ldots,O_n,\ldots$ such that $X \subset \cup O_n$ but there is no finite subcovering. Construct the sequence $A=(x_n)$ such that $x_n \in X \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i $ . But our assumption $A$ has an limit point $x$ , we say that $x \in O_N$ for some $N$ . Let $$A'=\{x_N ,x_{N+1}, ... \}$$ then we can see $x$ is not a limit point of $A'$ , since $x \in O_N $ but $O_N$ contains no element of $A'$ .

My question:
Is there any counterexample such that : $X$ is a topology space , every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point but $X$ is not compact .

Comment: The real numbers?

Comment: @AlkaKadri I think $N$ is an infinite set of $R$ which has no limit point .

Comment: Ah very nice. Just thought about it some more, and I think you might want to consider spaces where compact and sequentially compact are not equivalent. For example, https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/sasms_F04.pdf and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/compactness-sequentially-compact

Comment: Do you know about ordinal numbers? Well-ordered sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $x$ is a limit point of $A$ implies that it is a limit point of $A\setminus F$, where $F \subseteq A$ is finite, will hold in any $T_1$ space (so when singletons are closed). That answers the first part of your question.

In a $T_1$ space, being a limit point of $A$ (every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A\setminus\{x\}$) is equivalent to $x$ being an $\omega$-limit point of $A$ (every neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$).

"Every infinite set $A$ has an $\omega$-limit point" is in general spaces equivalent to "every *countable* open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover", i.e. countable compactness, which for metrisable spaces indeed is equivalent to compactness but in general not: consider $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal in the order topology, or $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\underline{0}\}$, which are countably compact but not compact. The first is also sequentially compact, first countable, hereditarily normal etc., so even for very nice spaces these notions need not be equivalent.