# Bolzano-Weierstrass property think of it conversely

Tags: compactness

I am reading this Bolzano-Weierstrass property saying that a metric space X is sequentially compact if every sequence in X has a convergent subsequence. I also read a theorem saying that sequentially compact is equivalent to compact.

So I am thinking of this sequence$a_{2k-1}=1, a_{2k}=n$. this sequence obviously has a convergent subsequence, but it is not bounded above.
How to prove that an unbounded space is compact? given that compact preserves boundedness in real metric.

Comment: " I also read a theorem saying that sequentially compact is equivalent to compact." This is true for metric spaces but false (in both directions) for general topological spaces. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/compactness-sequentially-compact

Comment: What you call "Bolzano-Weierstrass" "property" is the *definition* of sequential compactness, for general topological spaces (not necessarily metrizable).

Comment: Your last sentence "compact preserves boundedness in real metric" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

An unbounded metric space is not compact, as given any $x \in X$,  the open balls $B(x, n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is an open cover that does not have a finite subcover.

The sequence above does indeed have a convergent subsequence, but to apply the property that sequentially compact is equivalent to compact for metric spaces, you need **all** sequences to have a convergent subsequence, not just that particular one.

Comment: I see where I was wrong. Thanks!!