# Infinite Sets in Compact Spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Given that:

$S$ is a compact set in the topological space $(X, \mathcal T)$

$T\subset S$ has no accumulation points in S

How do I show that $T$ is finite?

Comment: Why the label about topological vector spaces?

Comment: Sorry! I have updated the labels.

Comment: Put a neighborhood around every point, and compact gives you a finite covering. Can you get only finite points in each of those neighborhoods?

Comment: Check my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424473/compactness-and-limit-points/424507?noredirect=1#comment907053_424507, actually I proved the contronominal.

Comment: @Lano Careful, sequences don't capture all the information in general topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the primary school precisation, I know it works perfectly only in first countable spaces, just read carefully what I wrote. If it's infinite it has a countable subset, which has no accumulation point and you get the absurd.

Comment: Do you mean limit point? I think *accumulation point* only applies to sequences.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff True; but any sequence with pairwise distinct terms has an accumulation point nonetheless. And from any infinite set you can build a sequence of this kind. What isn't true in general is that the accumulation point is the limit of a *subsequence*, but this is not relevant for this question.

Comment: @egreg: exactly what I meant :)

Comment: @Lano How unfortunate you chose to reply in that way to my comment. I did miss your idea, but I think that remark is uncalled for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $s \in S$ we find a neighbourhood $U_s$ that intersects $T$ in only at most finitely many points, so $U_s \cap T$ is finite (possibly empty). This is because no point in $S$ is an accumulation point of $T$ by assumption.

As the $U_s$ ($ s \in S$) form an open cover of $S$ by compactness we find a finite subcover $U_{s_1},\ldots,U_{s_n}$.

So $$T= T \cap S \subset T \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n U_{s_i}) = \cup_{i=1}^n (T \cap U_{s_i})$$

where the first follows from $T \subset S$, the inclusion from the fact that we cover $S$, and  the last equality is the standard distributive property of intersection over unions.

It follows that $T$ is a subset of a union of finitely many finite sets, so itself finite.