# Are the measurable subsets closed under the symmetric distance metric?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Define the following pseudo-metric on the set of measurable subsets of $R$:
>
> $$D(A,B)=\operatorname{Length}((A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)),$$
>
> i.e., the distance between $A$ and $B$ is the measure of their symmetric distance.
>
> Is the set of measurable subsets of $R$ closed under this metric?

After reading a recent answer by Conifold, [Compactness of a set of partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840069/compactness-of-a-set-of-partitions), showing that the subspace of measurable functions is not closed under another the Tychonoff topology, my guess was that the set of measurable subsets is also not closed. So I tried to look for a counter-example consisting of:

- A sequence of sets $A_1,A_2,...$, all measurable;
- A non-measurable set $L$;

Such that the sequence $A_i$ converges to $L$ under $D$. But I am not exactly sure how to define this convergence. Initially I wrote: $M(A_i\setminus L \cup L\setminus A_i)$ converges to 0, but following a comment by GEdgar, I am not sure I can write this because $M$ is not defined on $L$.

Here is my attempt:

Define a sequence of finite sets that converges the set of rational numbers:

- Define some linear ordering on the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.
- For every $i>0$, define $Q_i$ as the rational numbers up to and including the $i$th rational number in that ordering.

Now define the sets $A_i$ using the "[Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)" construction but taking $Q_i$ instead of $Q$.

Every $Q_i$ is finite, so the $A_i$'s are measurable. However, $Q_i$ converges to $Q$ so $L$ is a Vitaly set which is not measurable.

I am not convinced by this counter-example... can you provide a better one?

Comment: So, you have $M$ defined for non-measurable sets?  I assume you do, since you wrote $M(A_i\setminus L \cup L\setminus A_i)$.

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618480/what-is-the-definition-of-a-measurable-set) might be related

Comment: I have to admit that I'm always finding it strange and amusing when someone gives a formatted link to Wikipedia and has a typo in the formatting, which is really just repeating the title. To be more to the point, **Vitali** and not **Vitaly**. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the distance between any two real sets $A,B\subset\Bbb R$ as $d(A,B)=\lambda^*(A\Delta B)$, where $\lambda^*$ is the [Lebesgue outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) and $\Delta$ is the [Symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

This turns the power set of $\Bbb R$ modulo [null sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set#Lebesgue_measure) into a metric space.

The question you are asking is whether the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets is a closed subset of this metric space.

The answer is *affirmative*.

Suppose $A_n\rightarrow A$, i.e., 
$$\lambda^*(A\Delta A_n)\rightarrow 0$$
where $A_n$ is measurable, i.e., for any $X\subset\Bbb R$, 
$$\lambda^*(X)=\lambda^*(X\cap A_n)+\lambda^*(X\cap A_n^c)$$
 (where $Z^c=\Bbb R \backslash Z$ is the complement of set $Z\subset \Bbb R$).

The proof consists of the following exercises:

1. $\lambda^*(A^c\Delta A_n^c)\rightarrow 0$
2. $\lambda^*(X)\le\lambda^*(X\cap Y)+\lambda^*(X\cap Y^c)$ for all $X,Y\subset\Bbb R$
3. $\limsup \lambda^*(X_n)\ge \lambda^*(X) $ if $X_n\rightarrow X$

Comment: Thanks! It will take me some time to solve the exercises, but at least now I know how to state the question precisely.