# Function is continuous iff it's graph is compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\text{Dom}(f)=E$ be compact and $G_f=\{(x,f(x)): x\in E\}$ the *graph* of $f$.

$G_f$ is compact **iff** $f$ is continuous on $E$.

**Proof:** $\Rightarrow$ Let $f$ is not continuous at some point $x_0\in E$. Then $\exists \{x_n\}$ on $E$ such that $x_n\to x_0$ but $f(x_n)\nrightarrow f(x_0)$. It means that exists some subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $|f(x_{n_k})-f(x_0)|\geqslant \varepsilon_0$ for some $\varepsilon_0>0$. We'll define function $g:x\mapsto (x,f(x))$. Then $g(x_{n_k})=(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k}))$ is sequence in $G_f$ which is compact. Thus this sequence has limit point in $G_f$ namely $(p,f(p))$. Hence $\exists \{k_j\}$ such that $g(x_{n_{k_j}})\to (p,f(p)).$ Hence $p=x_0$ and $f(x_{n_{k_j}})\to f(x_0)$ and we get contradiction. Right?

$\Leftarrow$ Let $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ be an open cover of $G_f$ i.e. $G_f\subset \cup _{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$. Consider "projections" of $G_{\alpha}$ to $E$ we define $F_{\alpha}:=\{x\in E: (x,f(x))\in G_{\alpha}\}.$ It's clear that $E\subset \cup _{\alpha}F_{\alpha}$. Also we define function $g:x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ and $g$ is continouos on $E\times f(E)$ since all his components are continuous. Then $g^{-1}(G_{\alpha})=F_{\alpha}$ is open for any $\alpha$. Since $E$ is compact then $\exists$ $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n$ such that $E\subset F_{\alpha_1}\cup \cdots\cup F_{\alpha_n}$. Then $g(E)\subset g(F_{\alpha_1})\cup\cdots \cup g(F_{\alpha_n})=G_{\alpha_1}\cup\cdots\cup G_{\alpha_n}.$ But $g(E)=G_f$.

Sorry if my topic is repeated but I solved it myself and canyone check my proof please?

I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you working with $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ explicitly? You are attempting to use "sequentially compact iff compact", which is only true in metric spaces.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, No. I'm considering the general case.

Comment: By the way it's problem from baby Rudin. And I don know what is sequentially compact. I think that I has little problem in first part of proof. Right? I'll edit it soon.

Comment: @RFZ Since $RFZ$ is compact, it is sequentially compact. Thus, there given $(x_n,f(x_n))$, there is a subsequence converging to $(x,f(x)) \in G_f$. This implies $f$ is continuous directly.

Comment: @RFZ Can you define "compact", then, please?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I thought on this about day but no any good results. **That's my sketch:** Let $f$ is not continuous then exists some sequence $\{x_n\}$ on $E$ such that $x_n\to x_0$ but $f(x_n)\nrightarrow f(x_0)$.
We'll define function $g:x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ and $\{g(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$=\{(x_n,f(x_n))\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is sequence in compact $G_f$. Hence it has some limit point in $G_f$, namely $(p,f(p))$. It's easy to see that $p=x_0$.  Hence $\exists \{n_k\}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x_0)$.

Comment: But I have the last question. How to use compactness of $E$ to get contradiction? Can you help me with this last part of proof?

Comment: Please define "compact", then. Do you mean "every open cover has a finite subcover"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Dear! I think that I solved problem. I will write my solution above and can you check it please? But I think that I nowhere used the compactness of $E$. Hmmm

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Yes I mean that definition. Also was theorem in baby Rudin which states that every infinite subset $E$ of compact set $K$ has limit point in $K$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, what can you say about my above proof?

Answer (score 1):

## Forwards direction

You said in the comments that your definition of "compact" was "every open cover has a finite subcover", and that you have never encountered sequential compactness in general metric spaces. Therefore, you're going to have to prove that if the space is compact, then it has the property that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Proofs of this [are widely available](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44907/whats-going-on-with-compact-implies-sequentially-compact). The step "this sequence has a limit point" relies on this theorem.

## Backwards direction

"$g$ is continuous on $E \times f(E)$" is badly phrased: you mean "$g$ is continuous as a function $E \to E \times f(E)$".

---

Otherwise, I think it's fine.

Comment: I'm not rely that "the product of two compact spaces is compact". We have sequence $(x_n,f(x_n))$ in $G_f$ which is compact. Thus it has limit point $(p,f(p))$ in $G_f$. It means that there is subsequence that converges to this $(p,f(p))$. Right?

Comment: True. I'll edit that out.